# How to configure Proxy Settings

Tags: networking

I tried to input proxy server address in proxy setting and saved it, but after closing that window all the setting got restored to previous versions when I tried to search in LAN settings I found that the LAN settings are Disabled.When I searched on Internet I found that to make any changes in proxy settings I have to do it through LAN settings which in My PC case is currently disabled. Please suggest any solution for it.

[PC LAN setting picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUEYK.png)

Answer (score 0):

please refer to :

> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/askie/2015/10/12/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-for-ie10-and-ie11-as-iem-is-not-available/

or

> https://whatismyipaddress.com/using-proxies

If the work you performed was in line with the above, your system may be compromised.

because I suppose, Repair windows register by Tweaking Tools"Windows repair Tools".
Use this tool, The damaged system settings are fixed.
And then you can do proxy settings again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason why the LAN settings is disabled in InternetExplorer, but I think you can bypass that using registry editor.

Open

> run -> regedit ->
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Connections

Once here, change the

*DefaultConnectionSettings* key to whatever it is you want to change to.
This should solve your problem.